# force download on mac

Tags: c#, macos, download, contenttype

I have a handler that handles download from my site.
but when I try to download a mp4 on Mac, it just opens another window and opens the movie in quicktime.

```
context.Response.ContentType = dd.Type.Mime;
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + dd.Document.FileName + "\"");
```

dd.Type.Mime = application/octet-stream

from what I know, application/octet-stream should force the download...

c#

Comment: And this happens in every Mac web browser?

Comment: I happens in both Safari and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

what about `content-Type: video/mp4` …?

Comment: I used to have that, but that also just opens it in quicktime